# Can't get Intel i1218-v networkadapter working on windows 10 or windows 8.1 pro

Tags: drivers, bios, ethernet

I recently decided to build a new PC. I bought the asus z97-a Mainboard which has an onboard intel i1218-v ethernet controller. I installed Windows 10 from DVD and downloaded the latest driver on the Intel drivers page. unfortunately I can't get the ethernet controller working (mainboard should be win10 ready according to the manufacturer). I already tried the following:

- installed the latest driver from Intel drivers page
- unzipped the drivers manually and installed it via device-manager
- installed the ethernet driver from DVD which came with the motherboard
- installed Windows 8.1 Pro instead of win10 and did all of the above again.

What disturbs me is, that the ethernet controller is not recognized by name when I don't have any drivers installed. When I install the driver, the ethernet controller gets recognized, but I get a code 10 failure which says "device could not be started".

The next step i wanted to try is to update the BIOS. I actually don't think it's necessary and also a bit dangerous since a BIOS update can cause many trouble. Could it be that I did something wrong with the cables when I built the PC? I think not because the device gets recognized.

**Update:** Updated BIOS from version 2501 to 2801 which is the most recent. still no ethernet.

**Update:** I unplugged everything and let the whole computer rest overnight, but unfortunately this also didn't solve my problem. Now I think it is most likely a hardware failure or something. Next step is to try an external network adapter and try to exchange the mainboard with another one if the vendor is generous enough...

Comment: This might sound odd but the last time I got this error... I completely unplugged my system, right down to the powercords, left it that way overnight, and turned it on the next day. Totally wouldn't hurt to try it

Comment: @JourneymanGeek thanks for the hint. my next step is to completely unplug all the cables which are connected to the mainboard and plug them back in. i'll wait one or two hours with plugging them back in, so there should not be any electricity anymore on any device.

Comment: Did the network card work when you installed Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i did now because the normal solution with BIOS and driver update didn't work: I put a new external network adapter into the PC and disabled intel lan adapter in BIOS. This is a workaround which solves the issue.